# How to re-trigger audio in jQuery when it hasn't finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm working on this simplest drum machine in jQuery. Very basic thing, no sequencer what so ever, just samples assigned to the keydown events on your PC keyboard. I basically got it all down, as you can see from the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    drumInit(4);
});

function drumInit(count){
    var samples = [];   
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sample = new Audio('sample-' + i + '.wav');
        samples.push(sample);
    }
    samples[2].volume = .3;
    samples[3].volume = .4;

    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        switch(e.which) {
            case 90:                
                samples[0].play();
            break;

            case 88:
                samples[2].play();
            break;

            case 67:
                samples[1].play();
            break;

            case 86:
                samples[3].play();
            break;

            default: return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();             
    });
}
```

As you can see, function `drumInit` is in control of samples loading into an array, which then is used to assign sounds to keydown events, each by each.
It all works pretty well.

My problem is: when I press same key for the second time very quickly (sample hasn't finished yet) it doesn't re-trigger. And I want it to. This way I can bang some sick patterns out of it, jungle style (;)).

I was trying to force-retrigger each key event on second press, something along these lines:

```
case 90:                
    samples[0].play();
    if(samples[0].playing) {
        samples[0].pause();
        samples[0].ended;
        samples[0].play();
    }
break;
```

But - as You can imagine - to no avail.
So, my question is: can I re-trigger an audio sample before it finishes? And If I can, how to go about it?
(Ideally, it would be perfect to start second press play without finishing the first one, but we can manage). Any and all help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the issue just set the `currentTime` field and play the sample:

```
samples[0].currentTime = 0;
samples[0].play();
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome!